# supermetal formation

Tags: geology

How would the supermetal known as Ledrine form under natural conditions?

Any environment within our solar system is eligible for this purpose.

Ledrine has the following properties:

- withstand impacts of 20gs minimum. preferably capable of withstanding impacts up to 100gs (i.e. Superman/flying type superhero/jet crashing in at mach 3-5).
- able to withstand 7–8 degree earthquakes.
- 3 times lighter than industrial steel.

and considering this will be a city's reinforcement material (like Chicago's buildings having reinforcements against the wind speeds)

***non-radioactive***

just putting that out there as redundancy. never can be too careful with the internet.

Comment: My google turned up nothing for Ledrine.  Did you just make it up?  Also re withstanding impacts: a 1 cubic kilometer cube of Ledrine will do fine, but a shack made of a thin sheet of Ledrine not so much.  The stability of a structure has a huge amount to do with the construction of the structure.

Comment: yes I made it up. It's for the same setting as my Yacht question. and ummm good to know about the cubic kilometer redundant of ledrine would do. *writes that down for spaceship hull*

Comment: It would form by magic.

Comment: @JustinThyme *facepalm* OTHER THAN HANDWAVE MAGIC.

Comment: This is an imaginary metal, why can't you just make up how it is formed? Since the metal doesn't exist, there is no 'answer' to how it forms. I am voting to close this question as 'primarily opinion-based' because it is asking for someone to make up a story for you.

Comment: Please clarify if you mean 'element' or 'metal'? Do alloys qualify? They are not pure elements, but they are considered metals.

Comment: Are there any metals among the theoretical island of stability elements?

Comment: This sounds like the mighty element known as Handwavium

Comment: Downvoted: You aren't asking a meaningful question. You need to do a bit more homework:  Read up on materials science.  Most rocks fill your requirements.  *** That said: scale is important.  I can drop a mouse from a mile up, it survives.  Drop an elephant 3 feet it's dead.  A grasshopper can leap many times it's own length. Scale a grasshopper up to human size, it can't move.  Look at the structure of digging machines ranging from shovel to the giant multimillion pound ones used in open pit mines.  You will see by the bracing how scale comes into things.

Answer (score 5):

Your super metal is [aluminum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aluminium).

It is a third the weight of steel.
It is non radioactive.

As regards its performance in structures, that is up to your engineers.  One can make a temple out of bamboo that withstands a typhoon.  One can make a skyscraper out of steel girders that falls down a few months later.  Let them use the aluminum to make structural elements that suit their needs, and assemble them in ways that pass your proposed stress tests.

Aluminum is used extensively for construction, but generally in structures where the light weight as worth the added cost - for example, planes.
[image: aluminum structural elements]

http://www.tms.org/pubs/journals/JOM/0102/Sanders-0102.html

We have some aluminum here on earth.

Comment: Al on earth is not found as a metal, but needs high energy processing to isolate the pure element.

Comment: Also, from Wikipedia : "One important structural limitation of aluminium alloys is their fatigue strength. Unlike steels, aluminium alloys have no well-defined fatigue limit, meaning that fatigue failure eventually occurs, under even very small cyclic loadings." and "Another important property of aluminium alloys is sensitivity to heat." Basically...  aluminium is not a good choice for permanent structural elements, so using it for "city reinforcement" would probably end with collapsed buildings. And while there wasn't convenient short quote, fires would be needlessly hazardous.

Comment: OK @Ville Niemi if you want to get into the weeds with this Ledrine concept.  We will use aluminum beryllium alloy.  "The Al-Be alloy with a high modulus-to-density ratio (3.8 times that of aluminum or steel) greatly reduces the chance of flexure and mechanical failure. "http://www.reade.com/products/aluminum-beryllium-al-be-alloy.

Comment: Additionnally you can introduce other elements to modify the structural properties of it (Carbon nanotube metal matrix composites for ex)

Comment: @Will My thoughts tended to an alloy as well. However, the key criterion was 'under natural conditions'. Not sure if this allows deliberate synthesis.

Comment: the mass produced verison used in structures is/are made in a lab. soooo go nuts? also I had no idea bamboo was that strong!

Comment: Al-Be doesn't really help. As you noted aluminium was already stiff enough to meet the criteria, the problems were with other properties. This is kind of academic as the question was about how the "super-metal" could form naturally and I doubt either of us has any idea how aluminium metal could form naturally given how reactive it is.